# accessing database, messagebox says "System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[Magazine_Project.MagazinesDataSet+tblMagaineRow]"

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to access the text of a certain field in a database file containing information about magazines (this is from a text book), the column headers are Code, magName, and Cost.  I am trying to locate and display the code "EX33" with a message box.  It is located in the first column under the code category.  However, when messagebox pops up it just says **"System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[Magazine_Project.MagazinesDataSet+tblMagaineRow]"**.
Any ideas?  Sorry its my first time working with databases.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Public Class frmMain

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MagazinesDataSet.tblMagazine' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblMagazineTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MagazinesDataSet.tblMagazine)

End Sub

Private Sub btnCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCode.Click
    ' displays the record whose Code field contains EX33
    Dim strCode =
        From temp In MagazinesDataSet.tblMagazine
        Where temp.Code Like "EX33"
        Select temp

    MessageBox.Show("Code you are looking for: " &
                    strCode.ToString,
                    "Magazine thingz",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub

Private Sub btnName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnName.Click
    ' displays the record whose MagName field contains Visual Basic


End Sub

Private Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAll.Click
    ' displays all of the records


End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LINQ query always returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)` of some description.  If you want to get one item from that list then you use the `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` method as appropriate.

That's still going to give you a `DataRow` though, so calling `ToString` on that is useless.  If you want the value of a particular field in that row then you must retrieve it by name, either using the `Item` property or `Field` extension method.

Comment: interesting, can you give me an example how to implement this in my code?  I am trying to find the value of a particular field in that row.

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples you found on the web when you looked for yourself?

Comment: im just confused as to where and how to implement them (if the item property or field extension method is the fix).  looked up "datarow field extension method" Vb on google and yahoo, came up with alot of wierd stuff.  I have been trying Item(string) in various places with no luck.  I don't understand what i'm seeing on the web.  Can you explain how and why this is not working.  Sorry im just super confused.

Comment: How and why what's not working?  I already explain what the issue with the original code is.  I said that you need to call a method on the result of your LINQ query?  Have you done that?  If not, why not?  Have you looked up those methods specifically?  If not, why not?  Each of those methods will give you a DataRow object and then you simply use the Item property of Field method on that, the same as any other property or method.

Comment: its not working because whatever i do to it, messagebox displays "System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[Magazine_Project.MagazinesDataSet+tblMagaineRow]".  i tried using the methods, i dont know where the appropriate place is. How do u use Item or Field to retrieve it?  I tried every feasable thing i could think of. Have i called a method on the result of my LINQ query?  I think so, but im not sure what you mean by the result, is it strCode or temp?  I tried those it still displays the same.  Yes i have looked up every method i don't understand how to implement it in my code/get it to work.